# Tree postorder traversal in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

Tree traversal refers to the process of visiting each node in a tree data structure in a systematic way. The `postorder` traversal in the following image

[Sorted_binary_tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSorted_binary_tree.svg)

returns `A, C, E, D, B, H, I, G, F (left, right, root)`. The Prolog code for `PREORDER` traversal is

```
preorder(tree(X,L,R),Xs) :-
    preorder(L,Ls),
    preorder(R,Rs),
    append([X|Ls],Rs,Xs).

preorder(void,[]).
```

I would like to modify the above code to implement postorder traversal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a postorder you have to traverse the left branch and get a list of node values `Left`, then traverse the right branch and get a list of node values `Right`, and finally return the concatenation of Left, Right and the `node value`.

Therefore, to modify your code would be to rearrange the way in which you instantiate the resulting list:

```
postorder(tree(X, L, R), Xs):-
  postorder(L, Ls),
  postorder(R, Rs),
  append(Ls, Rs, Xs1),
  append(Xs1, [X], Xs).
postorder(void, []).
```

Note however, that this code is suboptimal in the sense that it is not tail recursive. You should consider implementing it with the aid of an accumulator.

Answer (score 5):

Folks, please consider using DCGs when describing lists, for example:

```
preorder(void) --> [].
preorder(tree(X, L, R)) -->
        [X],
        preorder(L),
        preorder(R).
```

Usage:

```
?- phrase(preorder(Tree), List).
```

You get different orders by simply deciding where to place the [X] in the sequence.